# Unable to display two ul lists in one line

Tags: html, css

I am displaying some products and I only have access to css in a magento go store. Right now the loop is set to display 5 products in a row and ul tag is closed. Then if more products exist a next `<ul>` element is created. I have fixed width which can accommodate 3 `<li>` items only. This is working nicely, but the problem is that on the second row only two items are displayed and next `<ul>` goes to next line. I don't want that to happen and want to display 3 items a row.

I have tried to add inline-block , and vertical align-top to the `<ul>` also list items are already vertically aligned to top, float:left and display:inline-block but somehow I am unable to fix this.

I would really appreciate if someone can help. Here is the url:

http://magoopaddleboards.gostorego.com/

Kind Regards,
Ahmar

Comment: set the loop for 6 products then?

Comment: I have only access to css cant do it via code @Mr_Green

Comment: you can't do it using just css.. what if the `li` elements are four but not five? This must be changed dynamically.

Comment: @Mr_Green why not? no matter how many products if the products are displayed inline I don't see how it can't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.widget ul.products-grid{
 display:inline !important;
 float:none !important;
}
.widget ul.products-grid:after{display:none !important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you set 6 items instead 5 items in your magento, I am not experienced in magentocommerce but if I understand, magento can configure the numbers of items for each page

it's a shame that you can not include javascript in your code
this jquery code could solve your problems:

```
<script>
var newUl = $('<ul class="products-grid">');    
$('.widget-products > ul.products-grid').each(function() { 
       $(this).find('li.item').each(function() { 
            newUl.append($(this))
       });
       $(this).remove();
    });
$('.widget-products').append(newUl);
</script>
```

Nothing is impossible, searh and find how to include this :)

[How to Add Custom JavaScript in Magento Go](http://go.magento.com/support/kb/entry/name/how-to-add-custom-javascript/)

Comment: It is not a magento store it is a magento go store and only provides css customization and doesn't provide access to theme files. I mentioned it already in post

Comment: Edited answer to include a javascript solution and how to include javascript in magento Go